# programatically searching terms from termstore

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, term-store, term

I need sample code where user can search terms from termstore by entering some term in textbox?

I am actually finding, is there any search function available for searching terms ? Like for finding users from UserProfileManager, we have search function as:

```
 UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
                ProfileBase[] profiles = profileManager.Search(Request.QueryString["q"]);
```

We have profileManager.Search function as shown above, Similarly, I am wondering if this kind of search function is available for searching terms from termStore?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a webpart which can search for collection of terms using this method,

```
Term.GetTerms Method (String, Int32, Boolean, StringMatchOption, Int32, Boolean)
```

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee583004%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Here's some sample code,

```
 TaxonomyFieldValue v = null; // Notsurehowtodothisbit();
        TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
        if (session.TermStores != null && session.TermStores.Count > 0)
        {

            TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[0];
            Term t = termStore.GetTerm(v.TermGuid);
            Term parentTerm = t.Parent;   
            TermCollection childTerms = t.GetTerms();
        }
```

Once you have the tree, you may be able to use a caml query to generate a SPList.GetList query that brings back anything tagged that way.

I have not done an experiment in this regard...
But [Bart-Jan Hoeijmakers](http://insidesharepoint.net/post/Using-taxonomy-fields-in-Sharepoint-2010-Part-II.aspx) has

```
   private SPListItemCollection GetItemsByTerm(Term term, SPList list)
    {
        // init some vars    SPListItemCollection items = null;    
        SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;     // set up the TaxonomySession    
        TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
        // get the default termstore    TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[0];   
        // If no wssid is found, the term is not used yet in the sitecollection, so no items exist using the term   
        int[] wssIds = TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm(SPContext.Current.Site, termStore.Id, term.TermSet.Id, term.Id, false, 1);
        if (wssIds.Length > 0)
        {
            // a TaxonomyField is a lookupfield. Constructing the SPQuery       
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyTaxonomyField' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", wssIds[0]);
            items = list.GetItems(query);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

[Sample Code Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258722/how-does-one-get-all-child-terms-of-a-sharepoint-term-in-c/5268658#5268658)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is convert the list of your terms in something that is querable by LINQ and use it.
For example:

```
    TaxonomyFieldValue v = null;
    TermCollection childTerms = null;
    var session = new TaxonomySession(site);
    if (session.TermStores != null && session.TermStores.Count > 0)
    {
        var termStore = session.TermStores[0];
        var t = termStore.GetTerm(v.TermGuid);
        var parentTerm = t.Parent;   
        childTerms = t.GetTerms();
    }

    if (childTerms.Count > 0)
    {
      var res = childTerms.Cast(YourCustomClass).Where(w => w.Title.Equal("WhatISearch");
    }
```